# Environment variables declared in shell are not being read in my .env file

Tags: php, symfony, environment-variables

Using Windows 10

```
php bin/console make:migration

In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 112:

  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost
  ' (using password: YES)


In Exception.php line 18:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)


In PDOConnection.php line 39:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

**.env file**

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name?serverVersion=5.7"
```

I tried defining my environment variables both from inside my shell as well as inside .env file

```
set db_user=root
set db_password=12345678
set db_name=loremipsum
```

The only way I got this to work was by hardcoding my variables like so:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name?serverVersion=5.7"
```

I am not running a virtual environment.

Comment: Those are not interpolated variables, you should replace `db_user` etc in the url string with your actual values. If you wish to use individual variables you can take a look in the [`config/packages/doctrine.yaml`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#doctrine-dbal-configuration) file.

Comment: So I suppose I can stick to the hardcoded solution. Even though my .env file is ignored by git, I still feel that this is a bad practice.

Comment: What do you mean by "inside my shell"? Using `set db_user=root` won't affect a PHP process

Comment: Also, why not commit that `.env` file to your repository if you need it? There's no need to ignore that file

Comment: You can still use 'real' environment variables, you just have to change your configuration to read those. For instance, instead of defining `DATABASE_URL` in the `.env` file you can define it as a variable and it'll still work. Provided it's available for the CLI **and** webserver. And `.env` files [_should_ be commited](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/dot-env-changes.html), not the `.env.local` ones.

Answer (score 0):

From what you pasted, it seems like your .env file does not contain you DB connection information.

The DATABASE_URL in your .env file should contain all of the connection information. There is no interpretation of you shell env variable in there. Therefore, it will not translate db_user to "root" in the .env.

For example, your.env should look like this. You can omit the double quotes too in the .env

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:12345678@127.0.0.1:3306/loremipsum?serverVersion=5.7
```

Maybe you don't like having your credentials stored in that file. Symfony has a solution for you, secrets. https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/secrets.html
Basically, secrets will generate a decryption key for you .env files. Therefore you only need to secure the decryption key and be able to version control your .env files.